# how to change magento order status programatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, fatal-error

I'm using magento 1.9 and I have to change the order status from shipped to delivered, both status having the same state "complete"

How can I able to change this?

I have tried following code

```
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId(100000123);

$order->setData("state", "complete");
$order->setStatus("delivered");
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('A ser executada a rotina de recarga.', false);
$history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
$order->save();
```

But it gives

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on boolean in /app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

Comment: self resolved. 

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$order->addStatusHistoryComment('','delivered')
                    ->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)
                    ->setIsCustomerNotified(false);

 $order->save();

Comment: I have tried above code , state and status field updated. But we get the error message as "Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "325" already exist" `require_once "app/Mage.php";
     umask(0);
     Mage::app('default');  
     $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(403);
        $order->setData('state', "complete");
        $order->setStatus("complete");              
        $order->save();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have got and error "The Order State "complete" must not be set manually." I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711176/how-to-set-order-status-as-complete-in-magento

Answer (score 7):

you can change order status as below:

```
$orderId = YOUR_ORDER_ID;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

$orderIncrementId = YOUR_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);

/**
 * change order status to 'Completed'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Pending'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Pending Paypal'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Processing'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Completed'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Closed'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Canceled'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Holded'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED, true)->save();
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives error "The Order State "complete" must not be set manually."  I want to change status not state of order.

Comment: $order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
    $order->setStatus(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order was set to Complete by our automation tool.', false);
    $order->save();